# How to animate inserted objects in an ItemsControl with a slide-in animation?

Tags: wpf, animation

After looking at several examples on this site it appears that the type of animation I wanted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58782870/animating-objects-of-observablecollection-when-items-are-added) is not that hard. Right now I've this in my `xaml`:

```xml
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Name="Info">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="Anim">
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Info" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="1" />
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Anim}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

an in code, I'm adding last item in first place in this way:

```cs
MyCollection.Insert(0, new Transaction()
{
    Name = ItemName + "   ",
    Quantity = QuantityTraded, 
    Price = AtPrice
});
```

With all these new item fades in on the left corner and pushes all existing items to the right BUT the behavior is snappy! I want a translate instead of opacity and for that I've to have this in `StackPanel` inside `DataTemplate`:

```xml
<StackPanel.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</StackPanel.RenderTransform>
```

What do I have to have in `Storyboard` for `TranslateTransform`? 
Will it animate all existing items or those will snap to their target position as they do with these code?

I've tried with blend which inserted these:

```xml
<b:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <b:FluidMoveBehavior Duration="0:0:5" AppliesTo="Children">
        <b:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
        </b:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseY>
        <b:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
            <BackEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
        </b:FluidMoveBehavior.EaseX>
    </b:FluidMoveBehavior>
</b:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

inside `ItemsControl` but that didn't change the behavior!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point, you could animate the `Width` property of the `StackPanel` from `0` to its maximum width. This will indeed push all items to the right as the first item grows.

```xml
<Storyboard x:Key="Anim">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Info" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="100" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

[image]

But animating the `Width` might not be the visual effect you intend.

You could elaborate on that and instead animate the `Width` of an outer element that will crop your inner `StackPanel`:

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Outer" Margin="5">
        <StackPanel x:Name="Info" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Anim">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Outer" 
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="50" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Anim}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

[image]

You might have to do some adjustments from here to remove any hardcoded values in the animations.